# Java: problem with JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, int, joptionpane

I'm making a simple program that takes input for 3 integers (n1, n2, n3) so for example if the 3 numbers were 6,12,4 it should return:

```
Integers entered: 6,12,4  
Sum = 22  
Average = 7.33...  
Smallest = 4  
Largest = 12
```

This is displayed in a text box using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog. The code is put in a loop so that for every 3 integers entered, it will return the whats shown above. However when I run the program it shows the following:

```
Integers entered: 6,6,6  
Sum = 22  
Average = 7.33...  
Smallest = 6  
Largest = 6
```

the values for n2,n3, smallest and largest show the value for n1. Here's the code inside the loop that's giving me problems:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, title);
String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1st integer: ");
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 2nd integer: ");
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
String num3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 3rd integer: ");
int n3 = Integer.parseInt(num3);

int sum = n1 + n2 + n3; //find sum
double avg = (double)sum/3; //find average

//find smallest integer
int smallest = n1;
if(n2 < smallest) n2 = smallest;
if(n3 < smallest) n3 = smallest;

//find largest integer
int largest = n1;
if(n2 > largest) n2 = largest;
if(n3 > largest) n3 = largest;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Integers entered: " + n1 + ", " + n2 + ", " + n3 
                + "\nSum = " + sum
                + "\nAverage = " + avg
                + "\nSmallest = " + smallest
                + "\nLargest = " + largest);
```

How do I fix it so that n2,n3,smallest,largest display their correct values?

Comment: `if(n2 < smallest) n2 = smallest;` Why are you overwriting the number you entered? Shouldn't it be `smallest = n2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assigning the value of `smallest` and `largest` back into `n2` or `n3`, depending on the result of the evaluation...

```
if(n2 < smallest) n2 = smallest;
if(n3 < smallest) n3 = smallest;

//find largest integer
int largest = n1;
if(n2 > largest) n2 = largest;
if(n3 > largest) n3 = largest;
```

Try something more like...

```
if(n2 < smallest) smallest = n2;
if(n3 < smallest) smallest = n3;

//find largest integer
int largest = n1;
if(n2 > largest) largest = n2;
if(n3 > largest) largest = n3;
```